# When Outlook Express starts it gives an error that doesn't say what happened?

Tags: windows, outlook-express

I have a problem with Outlook Express. Everytime when I want to start the program, it's showing me an error. Outlook Express encountered problem, and it will close. I can click on send report to Microsoft or Close. I can't use it, because it every closes itself.

I have tried Windows system restore but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post the windows (application) event log entry relating to this crash? It'll help zero down on the problem.

Comment: Could you say me what I need to search for in the file? In my opinion it will be too long if I post it here :) Is there anything special what I need to look for?

Comment: Please be advised, unless you have a very specific reason to use Outlook Express, don't use it. It is [unsupported and unmaintained](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/download-outlook-express). There are alternatives like [Windows Live Mail](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials-other-programs?T1=t2) and [Thunderbird](http://www.getthunderbird.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks! But could you help me in my error problem? :(

Comment: You did not specify the error you are getting, so nobody can help with useful ideas because it could be anything. We can give more detailed help if you give specific details about the problem. As for your crash, that sounds like Windows is damaged, which may (probably) also account for your OE issues. Try doing a repair-install of Windows (assuming you haven’t already by now).

Answer (score 1):

If [clearing the message store](http://web.archive.org/web/20041119165531/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/IE/community/columns/filecorruption.mspx) (at least temporarily) did help, then hopefully only the Folders database needed to be erased (which then means you need to re-create all your folder hierarchy). If the whole message stored needed to be removed for OE to work again, you may need to use some [tools to recover your messages](http://www.oehelp.com/).

If clearing the message store did not help at all, try [reinstalling OE](http://www.ctimls.com/Support/KB/How%20To/Repair_Outlook_Express.htm)<sup>[[1](http://web.archive.org/web/20041119165531/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/IE/community/columns/filecorruption.mspx)](http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpresstroubles/qt/et_reinstall_oe.htm), [[2](http://www.oehelp.com/)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278909)</sup>.

I have a little batch file, `Reinstall OE.bat` that I made with the basics that were needed the last time I needed to fix OE:

```
msimn /reg
regsvr32 urlmon.dll
regsvr32 mshtml.dll
regsvr32 shdocvw.dll
regsvr32 browseui.dll
regsvr32 msjava.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Express won't start.
This is usually due to a conflict between what is recorded in the registry and what is in the message store. Often, one can fix this problem by deleting the "folders.dbx" file. Search your hard drive for it.

[Source of Information](http://www.oehelp.com/OETips.aspx#7) see #7

.

It can also be due to a corrupt message store, which can be harder to fix.

[More Information](http://web.archive.org/web/20050204010502/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/IE/community/columns/filecorruption.mspx)